# TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined error in Backbone with Django-Tastypie

Tags: django, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, tastypie

I'm writing a simple example to learn Backbone and Django-Tastypie. I'm using Backbone.js 1.0.

In the console, when I try `notes = new NoteListView();` I get the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined`.

From what I've read online, I THINK that it's because the template isn't instantiated. But, the template is cached in the template call on the View. So, I'm confused.

Maybe my thinking is completely wrong, but what supposed to happen is the bind happens on the template that has been cached so that it can do the set and populate the template.

The TastpieCollection and TasttypieModel come from http://paltman.com/2012/04/30/integration-backbonejs-tastypie/ which seems to work really well.

```
$(function() {

    // Note: The model and collection are extended from TastypieModel and TastypieCollection
    // to handle the parsing and URLs

    window.Note = TastypieModel.extend({});

    window.Notes = TastypieCollection.extend({
        model: Note,
        url: NOTES_API_URL
    });

    window.NoteView = Backbone.View.extend({

        template: _.template($('#notes-item').html()),

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.model.bind('set', this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    })

    window.NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        template: _.template($('#notes-item-list').html()),

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.collection.bind('set', this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
            var $notes,
                collection = this.collection;
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            $notes = this.$('.notes');
            collection.each(function(note){
                var view = new NoteView({
                    model: note,
                    collection: collection
                });
                $notes.append(view.render().el);
            });
            return this;
        }
    })
})
```

So, two questions:

**Question One:** What is the error saying and how do I fix it?

**Question Two:** The `set` is the new version of how `reset` was used... correct?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `model: Note` should be `model: note`. There is not `'set'` event, there are `'add'`, `'remove'`, and `'change'` events.

Comment: I made two changes, Note to note and the notes.append was in the wrong place. Both fixed.

Comment: I'm confused about the events having no set. I'm getting this from the docs at backbone.js here: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set

Comment: The `Collection#set` docs say that "All of the appropriate `'add'`, `'remove'`, and `'change'` events are fired as this happens" and that happens because that's what `set` does, it just figures out what combination of additions, removals, and changes are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting a collection, that is the reason of your error message. You should do something like this to fix that specific error message:

```
notes = new NoteListView({collection : new Notes()});
```

Comment: Where would I do that though? In the view.initialize? In the view.render?

Comment: I figured it out. I either need to have it in the initialize function or add in manually in the console. In the future, I'll add it via the router.